# Elasticsearch Completion Suggester: Document body as Payload

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html). During indexing I can specify `payload` which will be returned. Is it possible to return whole document as a `payload` without copying same data from document body to `payload` during indexing?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this lately? - even I am having the same question.